# Unable to load css files in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have the CI installation configured in my apache conf and hosts files such that I can open it by pointing my browser to:

```
http://mysite/
```

Above URL will open the index file configured and everything works fine.

Now in this CI installation I added a CSS file at:

```
application/assets/css/site.css
```

And in my config file I added:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mysite/';
```

If I do an echo `$base_url()` I get `http://mysite/` so it works fine.

Now to load the css file I do `$siteCss = base_url('assets/css/site.css')`

This shows me `http://mysite/assets/css/site.css` as expected, but if I open that URL in browser it gives 404 error.

In my .htaccess I have added a few lines to remove index.php from the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

How can I correctly load my css files in this setup?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Put your `assets` directory in project root directory and this is best practice. so your `site.css` path should be

```
assets/css/site.css
```

instead of

```
application/assets/css/site.css
```

and now test. Now `$siteCss = base_url('assets/css/site.css')` will work

Comment: This is correct. `application` directory is not meant neither made to be reached from URL (e.g. client's browser) respecting security standards of MVC architecture.